# Port Forwarding for Minecraft Server Timed Out

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, minecraft

To preface: I've looked at 20 different questions about this exact topic and not a single one solved my issue.

I'm trying to forward port 25565 to my computer to allow friends to connect to a Minecraft server I'm hosting.

Things to know:

- My local IP is correct.
- My external IP is correct.
- I have a rule for both TCP and UDP.
- My router firewall allows all incoming connections.
- Windows firewall allows all instances of Java to accept connections, and I have rules to allow all connections on port 25565 for both TCP and UDP.
- My server is running on port 25565 when I try to check with canyouseeme.org and to check if a friend can connect to it.
- A friend has yet to be able to connect to it. The connection times out.
- canyouseeme.org has yet to successfully see the server on port 25565.
- I can connect to the server with my local IP.

What can I do?

Comment: Is your ISP giving you a public IP address? Sometimes you will get a local IP address, I know it sounds weird, You could test this by hosting a web server on port 80 an just seeing if connections to your public IP can see a testpage.html Don't forget to allow port 80 forward to your static HOST IP

Comment: Yes, I have a public IP address. It's 138.229.xxx.xxx. My internal address is 192.168.1.16.

Comment: If you open up Wireshark while your friend (or canyouseeme) does the test, does it show the computer receiving connection attempts (TCP SYNs)? If it does, Windows problem. If it doesn't, router or ISP problem.